# What are some good / feature rich mail clients that support Exchange?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, email, exchange

I'm a developer at my small office and we exclusively use Exchange 365 for our email, and I am getting incredibly tired and frustrated of the web interface. I would like to use a local mail client.

Postbox looked great, but some research reveals it does not natively support Exchange. I would like to have a client similarly feature rich (particularly when it comes to tagging/organization), but natively supports Exchange protocols.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I'll state the obvious one: [Outlook:Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/outlook) supports Exchange natively, including support for Exchange's categories (which Exchange uses instead of tags)

There are third-party add-ins like [MailTags](http://www.indev.ca/MailTags.html) which add support for categories/tags to Apple Mail.

Thunderbird + ExQuilla doesn't support categories/tags.

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative to Postbox would be the [Thunderbird.](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) made by the FireFox makers.

It can [work with exchange server](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/connect-the-thunderbird-email-client-to-your-exchange-server/).